# How to increase Google Cloud GPU quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, quota

I'm new to Google Cloud and I'm trying to set up a VM to do some deep learning experimenting, exploiting Google free credits.

I set up a Linux VM with a Tesla K80 attached and I now have to request a GPU quota increase in the same region the VM is located in (us-central1-a, in my case). So, I navigate to the Quotas tab, search for NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPUs and try to select the correct region in order to edit the limit, but I run in the following issue: us-central1 zone has a Tesla K80 GPU limit set to 1 and I am able to edit it. On the other hand, us-central1-a (which is the specific location of my VM instance) is not editable and has the same limit set to 0. Actually, this pattern repeats for every regional zone available.

At first I subscribed with a free account to redeem the free credit, but next I upgraded the account, so I should be able to edit the quotas! Does anyone knows what the problem could be?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#request_quota) To request GPU quota, use Cloud Console. For more information about requesting quotas, refer to [Requesting additional quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) in the Compute Engine documentation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, incurring in the issue above.

Comment: You need wait 48 hours to activate the resources for the project if resources are not available after that contact [sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact)